# Jlink is unable to derive module descriptor?

Tags: java, java-10, jlink

I have a hello-world application that I have compiled into a `.jar`.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world. ");
  }
}
```

Now I would like to use JLink to create a self-contained executable:

```
$ jlink --output testout --module-path ./out
Error: Unable to derive module descriptor for ./out/hello-app.jar
```

- What does this error mean?
- How can I fix this?

---

```
$ javac -version
javac 10.0.1

$ jlink --version
10.0.1
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

Update:

I have added a `--add-modules` flag. Now my command is:

```
jlink --module-path $(location :hello-app) --add-modules hello --output $OUT
```

I have added a `module-info.java` file. My source tree:

```
$ tree src/
src/
├── hello
│   └── Main.java
└── module-info.java
```

And `module-info.java`:

```
module hello {

}
```

However, now the error message is:

> Error: Module hello not found

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you added a `module-info.java` file to your project?

Comment: I assume there are two issues here. One is that the command doesn't have a `--add-modules` option so it's not clear which modules you are looking to include in the run-time image. Second is the error message, which does suggest hello-app.jar doesn't contain an explicit module.

Comment: Fixes those issues and updated the question

Comment: @sdgfsdh Does `hello-app.jar` indeed have a `module-info.class` file? Please, make sure.